# how to run all csv data to getting data using curl

Tags: php, api, csv, curl

I have created a php script to get csv file first row and getting data from curl but it only show last id's data.
Here is my code:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("file1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        
        $id = $data[0]. "<br />";

        

    }

    fclose($handle);
}

$entity = getData($id);
    if($entity->success){
    $websites = $entity->data->websites;
    $web = $websites[0];
    $website_address = $web->website_url;
    echo "Website Address: $website_address <br>";
}



function getData($id){
    $api_endpoint = 'url';
    $data = array();
    $data['api_key'] = 'abcdef';   
    $data['e_id'] = $id;
    $url = $api_endpoint."?".http_build_query($data);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $obj= json_decode($output);

    return $obj;

}
```

my csv data is like:

```
960626888790016
437728935677953
960626888790016
438798134112256
999649717096448
```

But after getting curl data from api I only get last id's data. I want all data separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following to invoke cURL for each of your id's in the csv file.

1. Build an array `$ids` with the id's from the csv file
2. `foreach()` to invoke `getData()` and run cURL on each seperate `id`

.

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("file1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $ids[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
//flatten the array with id's
$ids = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $ids);
// cURL for each id
foreach($ids as $id) {
    $entity = getData($id);
    if ($entity->success) {
        $websites = $entity->data->websites;
        $web = $websites[0];
        $website_address = $web->website_url;
        echo "Website Address: $website_address <br>";
    }
}


function getData($id){
    $api_endpoint = 'url';
    $data = array();
    $data['api_key'] = 'abcdef';
    $data['e_id'] = $id;
    $url = $api_endpoint."?".http_build_query($data);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $obj= json_decode($output);

    return $obj;

}
```

Comment: i only need the first row of data: `$id = $data[0]. "<br />";` but if i use this got some errors:  Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, string given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/readCSV/test.php on line 11

Comment: This is working code - it builds an array with the id's to run through cURL one at a time, but if that is not your requirement I'll delete the answer. If you want to just run cURL for one id, e.g. `$ids[0]`, then delete the `foreach()` loop and just feed `getData[$ids[0])`...

Comment: there are several rows in csv file thats why I only need the first row so this first row have ids only but you wrote `$data` only it returns all data, i need only first row of csv file do you got my point?

Comment: I've taken your sample csv data verbatim, maybe I shouldn't have... See if you get it to work, otherwise I'll delete and leave it to someone else.

Comment: @shawn consider accepting and/or up-voting the answer if it helped you :)